# Регулярное выражение для разбиения на массивы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Какое рег. выражение нужно для `preg_split`, чтобы такая строка

`id('1,443,43'),text('texts')`

разбилась на массивы:

```
 [1] => "id('1,443,43')" 
 [2] => "text('texts')"
```

Вот что я сделал, не работает(

```
$qact = preg_split("/,^[a-zA-Z].*'/", $query0[2]);
```

Помогите пож-та, а то хз как применять регулярки для разделения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще можно так:

```
<?
  $var = "id('1,443,43'),text('texts')";
  $res = array();
  preg_match_all('/[^\,\(\)]+\(.*?\)(?:,|$)/m', $var, $res );
  print_r( $res );
?>
```

Но "хакнуть" всё равно можно... `id('abcd),')`

Comment: Спасибо, код работает. А можно ли как то быстро стереть запятую у всех членов массива? А то запятая остаётся у всех кроме последнего и элементы не аналогичные получаются. Конечно можно пройтись по всем с помощью цикла и почистить substr, но может как-то попроще можно? Блин, т.е. при забивке нужно будет поменять программно все скобочки на какое нибудь служебное слово?

Comment: Нужно знать откуда данные, что это за данные, etc....